# Having trouble making the Sierpinski Carpet using recursion only and python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
window.screensize(1920,1080)
window.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0, startx=None, starty=None)

# T is a global variable 
T = turtle.Turtle()
T.shape('turtle')
T.speed(2)

def forward_and_rotate(distance, degree, t):
  t.forward(distance)
  t.left(degree)



def draw_square_recursion(distance, t, sides_left=4):
  t.pendown()
  if sides_left == 0:
    return
  else:
    forward_and_rotate(distance, 90, t)

    draw_square_recursion(distance, t, sides_left-1)
  t.penup()


def draw_filled_square(t, side_len, color='black'):
  current_color = T.pencolor()
  t.pendown()
  t.color(color)
  t.begin_fill()
  draw_square_recursion(side_len, t, 4)
  t.end_fill()
  t.penup()
  T.color(current_color)

# Starter code
def sier_carp(t, l, n):
  if n == 0:
    home = t.pos()
    t.goto(home + (l/3, l/3))
    draw_filled_square(t, l/3)
    t.goto(home)
  else:
      sier_carp(t, l/3, n - 1)
      t.fd(l/3)
      sier_carp(t, l/3, n -1)
      t.fd(l/3)
      sier_carp(t, l/3, n -1)
      t.fd(l/3)

      t.left(90)
      t.fd(l/3)

      sier_carp(t, l/3, n - 1)
      t.fd(l/3)
      sier_carp(t, l/3, n -1)
      t.fd(l/3)
      
      t.left(90)
      t.fd(l/3)

      sier_carp(t, l/3, n - 1)
      t.fd(l/3)
      sier_carp(t, l/3, n -1)
      t.fd(l/3)
      
      t.left(90)
      t.fd(l/3)

      sier_carp(t, l/3, n - 1)
      t.fd(l/3)
      sier_carp(t, l/3, n -1)
      t.fd(l/3)
      
      t.left(90)
      t.fd(l/3)

 

    # add more cases!


T.penup()
sl = 200
draw_square_recursion(sl, T, 4)
sier_carp(T, sl, 1)
```

I'm having a hard time drawing the Sierpinski carpet using recursion only and no loops. However after the first three squares are drawn and I try to rotate to the left and do the next 2 squares on the nest site, the squares go out of line. If you want you can try out this code and see how it looks like. Btw the color are inversed to white around and black inside and not the usual carpet version of black around and white square.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to do a simplied version of your code -- although repetitive, your starter code does achieve your goal of recursion only.  However, I'm going to use *stamping* instead of *drawing* so we can focus on the recursive image and not the mechanics of drawing squares with turtles:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SIDE_LENGTH = 200
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def draw_filled_square(t, side_len):
    t.shapesize(side_len / CURSOR_SIZE)
    t.stamp()

def sier_carp(t, l, n):
    draw_filled_square(t, l)
    
    if n < 1:
        return

    x, y = t.position()

    t.setx(x + l)
    sier_carp(t, l/3, n - 1)

    t.sety(y + l)
    sier_carp(t, l/3, n - 1)

    t.setx(x)
    sier_carp(t, l/3, n - 1)

    t.setx(x - l)
    sier_carp(t, l/3, n - 1)

    t.sety(y)
    sier_carp(t, l/3, n - 1)

    t.sety(y - l)
    sier_carp(t, l/3, n - 1)

    t.setx(x)
    sier_carp(t, l/3, n - 1)

    t.setx(x + l)
    sier_carp(t, l/3, n - 1)

    t.goto(x, y)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.penup()

sier_carp(turtle, SIDE_LENGTH, 4)

screen.exitonclick()
```

I intentionally avoided speeding things up with `screen.tracer(False)` as you should see how it's drawn in a counterclockwise pattern.

I believe the problem is simpler than you're making it.  It's important in this sort of drawing that your recursive function return the turtle to where it was when the function started.  This allows the caller to make valid assumptions about its position.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here are the concepts I've noted before starting:

1. Define a function that takes in a coordinate and a square size, and return the 8 surrounding coordinates.
2. Define a function that takes in a coordinate and a square size, and draw a square with the given size as its length, and the given coordinate as its center point.
3. Define the main function that will take in a coordinate, a size and the number of recursions. The coordinate will be the center of the Sierpinski Carpet and the size will be the size of the finished Sierpinski Carpet.

---

**With the above notes in mind, let's begin to construct our program:**

1. Import the `turtle` module, turn off tracer *(optional)* for efficiency and hide the turtle cursor:

```
import turtle

turtle.tracer(0)
turtle.hideturtle()
```

2. Define the function that takes in coordinate and a unit, and return a list of all 8 coordinates surrounding the given coordinate:

```
def surrounding(cor, size):
    x, y = cor
    return [(x - size, y + size),
            (x + size, y + size),
            (x - size, y - size),
            (x + size, y - size),
            (x - size, y),
            (x + size, y),
            (x, y + size),
            (x, y - size)]
```

3. Define a recursive function that will take in a coordinate, size and a count. It will draw a square with its center at the given coordinate and its size *one third* of the given size, so that the sides of the finished carpet will end up the given size. The count is there to tell the function when to stop recursing; when the count reaches `0`:

```
def draw_square(cor, size, count):
    size /= 3
    count -= 1
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(cor[0] - size / 2, cor[1] + size / 2)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(size)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(size)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(size)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(size)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
    if count:
        func(surrounding(cor, size), size, count)
```

4. Define a recursive function that takes in a coordinate and a size. It will use the `surroundings` function defined earlier to convert that coordinate into a list of surround coordinates. Then, it will use the `draw_square` function defined earlier to draw a square at each of the surrounding coordinates:

```
def func(cors, size, count):
    if len(cors) == 2:
        draw_square(cors, size, count)
    else:
        draw_square(cors[0], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[1], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[2], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[3], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[4], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[5], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[6], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[7], size, count)
```

5. Finally, call the main function, `func`, and update the `turtle` screen *(if tracer was set to `0`)*.

```
func((0, 0), 600, 5)
turtle.update()
```

**Altogether:**

```
import turtle

turtle.tracer(0)
turtle.hideturtle()

def surrounding(cor, size):
    x, y = cor
    return [(x - size, y + size),
            (x + size, y + size),
            (x - size, y - size),
            (x + size, y - size),
            (x - size, y),
            (x + size, y),
            (x, y + size),
            (x, y - size)]

def draw_square(cor, size, count):
    size /= 3
    count -= 1
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(cor[0] - size / 2, cor[1] + size / 2)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(size)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(size)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(size)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(size)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
    if count:
        func(surrounding(cor, size), size, count)

def func(cors, size, count):
    if len(cors) == 2:
        draw_square(cors, size, count)
    else:
        draw_square(cors[0], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[1], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[2], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[3], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[4], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[5], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[6], size, count)
        draw_square(cors[7], size, count)

func((0, 0), 600, 5)
turtle.update()
```

Output:

[image]